# GROUP_CONCAT split in different columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a TABLE, need logical help

This query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(tran_date, '%M %Y') AS month_name, 
    SUM(IF(c.ctype = 4, gl.amount * -1, 0)) AS sales,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(d.name)) AS d_name
FROM
    gl_trans AS gl, company_chart_masters AS a, 
    company_chart_types AS t, company_chart_classes AS c, dimensions as d   
WHERE 
    (c.ctype = 4 OR c.ctype = 5) AND
    d.id = gl.dimension2_id AND
    gl.account = a.account_code AND
    a.account_type = t.id AND
    t.class_id = c.id AND
    DIMENSION2_id = gl.dimension2_id
GROUP BY 
    month_name
ORDER BY 
    month_name DESC
```

Produces this result:

[image: query result]

As you can see the output of the query has 3 columns `month_name`,  `sale` and `pos` where the `pos` column is separated with comma. But what I want now is to split the pos in different columns (factor matab, Rawalpindi matab, ...).

My second problem is that I also split the `sale` column like a split the `pos` column ans show sale accordingly pos wise and this sale column also shows in different columns after splitting.

Is there any other way to split the RESULT and show each value in the column and same ROW? In the same result?

Expected result:

```
Month_name     Factor_Matab    Rawalpindi_Matab
-----------------------------------------------
feb 2020          25000            78236
mar 2020          26366            82367
```

As I am new at stack overflow so I don't know how to show this expected result in tabular form

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, *as tabular text*.

Comment: I think you are looking for conditional aggregation try searching for mysql pivot for examples.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  It is the 21st Century.

Comment: Does you have defined and limited columns count such as (factor matab, Rawalpindi matab, ...).

Comment: No columns count are not limited it's dynamic I mean (factor matab, Rawalpindi matab,another matab,and so on ...... ) depends on the user that how many matab they opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get your expectation you should to use `pivot table` pattern:

```
SELECT 
    month_name,
    -- pivot table
    SUM(IF(dimension = 'Factor_Matab', sales, 0)) AS Factor_Matab,
    SUM(IF(dimension = 'Rawalpindi_Matab', sales, 0)) AS Rawalpindi_Matab
FROM (
    -- Select data grouped by month and dimension as tmp
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(tran_date, '%M %Y') AS month_name, 
        d.name AS dimension,
        SUM(IF(c.ctype = 4, gl.amount * -1, 0)) AS sales
    FROM 
        gl_trans AS gl, 
        company_chart_masters AS a, 
        company_chart_types AS t, 
        company_chart_classes AS c, 
        dimensions as d   
    WHERE (c.ctype = 4 OR c.ctype = 5) AND
        d.id = gl.dimension2_id AND
        gl.account = a.account_code AND
        a.account_type = t.id AND
        t.class_id = c.id AND
        DIMENSION2_id = gl.dimension2_id
    GROUP BY month_name, d.name
) tmp
-- group tmp table by month
GROUP BY month_name 
ORDER BY month_name DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks alot @slava Rozhnev  "hats off to you"

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Because of "No columns count are not limited it's dynamic", you should also add a column like: `SUM(IF(dimension IN ('Factor_Matab','Rawalpindi_Matab'), 0, sales)) AS Other_Matab`